# Spring security username not displayed on error page which value is not specified

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-status-code-404

This is my error handler controller. it goes to the 404 page when links/urls does not exist. Im also using spring security. Basically, when user logs in, the username of the user will be displayed. But if the user mistypes or typed the wrong url/link, it displays the 404 error page but no username is displayed.

```
package com.syntacks.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HTTPErrorHandlers{

    String path = "/user";

    @RequestMapping(value="/400")
    public String error400(){
        return path+"/404";
    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/404")
     public String error404(){
         return path+"/404";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/500")
     public String error500(){
         return path+"/404";
     }


}
```

I've already added here the sec-authorize which determines if the users is logged in or not. This is placed on my every page.

```
    <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN">
    <a class="active" href="/Project/profile?user=${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}">${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="/Project/<c:url value='logout'/>">Logout</a></li>
                                        </ul>
</sec:authorize>
```

on the web.xml i added error-codes

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/400</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>123</error-code>
        <location>/123</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404</location>
    </error-page>
        <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/405</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

So if user type 404 or any value of the mapping i specified it return the username but if the value or link is not specified it simply displays the 404 page with Error page not found text with no displayed username. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">



     <security:http auto-config='true'>
            <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

            <security:intercept-url pattern="/questions/ask" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/profile" access="ROLE_USER" />    
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/view-tags" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="view-questions" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/view-users" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />                            
            <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>
            <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout" 
            invalidate-session="false"/>
        </security:http>


     <security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider>
                <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"  
                    users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"  
                    authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from users where username =?  " />
            </security:authentication-provider>
          </security:authentication-manager>
    </beans:beans>
```

Comment: Could you please share your spring security configuration.

Comment: @Mithun, i've added my spring-security.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line of code to get the currently logged in user:

```
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    authenticated as <security:authentication property="principal.username" /> 
</security:authorize>
```